# How to manipulate Excel entire row

Tags: python, excel, graph, rows

I'm trying to manipulate 4 entire rows in Excel.
I'm doing this because I have a graph that is being made by these values, but I want the graph to be updated with daily results. I am able to retrieve the new values I want to use for the graph, but I'm unsure how I can 'paste' these into Excel, any ideas?

I've tried: xlsxwriter, openpyxl,. But that didn't seem to get it te work.

I'm trying to figure out what the best solution is for this issue, as I'm struggling with it for a few days now.

Answer (score 0):

Use Pandas library get the dataframe from it

```
df = pd.read_excel('tmp.xlsx', index_col=0)
```

After that use matplotlib for graph on the same dataframe

```
df = df.cumsum()//any required method

df.plot();
```